# Hover State Detection of CSS 3D Elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, 3d

I have a simple button that has a 3d transformation on hover.

It works nicely in Firefox, but in Chrome the "hover zone" is smaller than the button. It feels inconsistent and very bad if the button does not instantly play the animation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsXkY/

The HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div class="link1">CONTACT</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is also pretty simple, but prefixed and includes some workarounds already:

```
.link1 {
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 230px;
height: 95px;
line-height: 95px;
background-color: rgba(20,20,20,0.9);
display: inline-block;
margin: 80px 90px;
font-weight: 200;
text-align: center;

-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;

-moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
-ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
-o-transform: perspective(1000px);
-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px);
transform: perspective(1000px);

transform-style: preserve-3d;

outline: 1px solid transparent; /* Workaround Firefox Anti Aliasing */
}

.link1:hover {
-moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px);
-ms-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px);
-o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px);
-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px);
transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px);
}
```

I'd be very happy if someone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an html element rotates, with no transformZ, part of it is intersecting with the body, because its laying flat against body on z-plane.

In your case, The right side is behind the body, so it can't respond to mouse events.
To fix this, use transform : translateZ to bring the element forwards.

example:

```
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg) translateX(25px) translateZ(200px);
```

can use transform: scale to counter the size increase.
try this fiddle in webkit:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZsXkY/2/

you will have to fine tune it to get the exact positioning that you want. remeber that you can set transform-origin to control the 'axis' along which the transform occurs.

Firefox seems to handle z-plane issues differently than chrome.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely works now (with the button jumping into your face, of course), could you show me a jfiddle with a transform-origin please? (The link you posted is not edited, it's the original one)

Comment: here is the updated fiddle also using transform scale to counter the translateZ  http://jsfiddle.net/ZsXkY/2/. working on the transform-origin...

Comment: here is an unrelated example of transform origin. its not always easy to see the difference in all cases, os I used rotateZ here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5G4c/2/

Answer (score 1):

For a simple workaround you can add

```
body {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-5000px);
  -moz-transform:translateZ(-5000px);
  transform:translateZ(-5000px);
}
```

solved the hover issue for me under chrome. But i would consider this an ugly hack, don't know how many side effects this could have.

btw. i also had no problem under firefox

Comment: +1 for the idea of bringing the body back int the z plane. if this makes the view shrink, transform scale can be used to reverse that. regarding firefox, it tends to perform better than chrome with 3d transforms. chrome fails to render parts of the screen if you combine 3D rotation on large elements with transform scale.  however, firefox has issues with z-index of overlapping 3d elements.